# How to let OPcache work correctly under chroot?

Tags: debian, php-fpm, chroot, opcache

There is PHP-FPM and OPCache (downloaded and compiled from php.net)

```ini
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.use_cwd = 1
zend_extension=opcache.so
```

php-fpm profiles run in chroot, i.e. `/home/user1/www/index.php` -> `/www/index.php`, `/home/user2/www/index.php` -> `/www/index.php`, what `index.php` see in both cases.

- `user1` have installed WordPress. `user2` have custom `index.php`.
- `user1`'s index.php was executed before `user2`'s `index.php`.

In such case, when I'm calling `index.php` from `user2` folder, I see compiled output of `index.php` from `user1` folder.

**Current solution**. I can run different PHPs per user **or** I must kill my beautiful structure `/home/user1/www` to `/home/user1/user1www/` cause OPcache need to see differ paths. Or I disable OPcache, but it affect perfomance.

Is there a way to keep `/home/user1/www`, `/home/user2/www`, etc and let OPcache work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is famous bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69090
which was present for years. But not anymore.

So, update your PHP version, and add this to `php.ini`:

```ini
opcache.validate_root=1
```

This will make cache keys unique per user, so even if there are two `/htdocs/wp-config.php` in two different chroot's, from now they will get two different cache entries.

Comment: Great news sir!

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to have unique paths inside the chroot to achieve your goal. This issue happens because the whole PHP-FPM worker is working inside the chroot, but it is using a global OPCache. Inside the chroot it simply cannot see anything else than `/www` in the beginning of the filename.

This could be fixed in the PHP codebase by using both pool name and filename as the cache key. However, since chroot is a special case, it hasn't been implemented as far as I know.

When I was implementing chroot PHP-FPM for one project, I made a structure like:

```
/srv/www/domain.com/domain.com/docroot
```

Where the chroot directory was `/srv/www/domain.com`. This way there is always an unique identifier inside the chroot for the filename so that cache key collisions do not happen.

Comment: Now that I looked more closely at it, there has been discussion about this issue in PHP bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69090. There has been a patch, but I don't know which PHP version has included the patch. The thread also reveals that the shared OPCache is a security issue.

Comment: yep, i've seen many issues in the web. It's why i asked here.

Comment: I will mark your answer as a solution, because.. there is no solution for chroot instead of unique patched inside chroot area. Hope PHP devs will fix it.